# Why is my binary(64) 60 char password hash shown as 60 characters in phpmyadmin, but upon exporting has four '\0's on the end?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, password-hash

I know \0 is ending strings. Why are there four? And why, in my php code, do I have to specifically take the substring of first 60 characters in order for `password_verify` to work? (e.g. `$passhash = substr($result, 0, 60);`)

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Why do you store it in a binary field?

Comment: @tkausl I was following bits of tutorials from all over and somehow ended up with that. Should I have used varchar(60)?

Comment: @MinimumEntropy That depends on what you're trying to store...

Comment: @tkausl I am storing the output of PHP's `password_hash` function

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Store this as `VARCHAR(255)` if you *must*. `BINARY` columns are for binary data *only*.

Comment: @tadman I doubt I'd hold Laravel up as the gold standard for this...

Comment: @Brad If you have any other suggestions of one that's tested, proven, and community supported, by all means let me know. I like to advertise alternatives because home-rolled is never the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is simply not displaying this to you.

You have a 64-byte field.  It's always going to be 64 bytes.  If you have 60 bytes used, the last four are going to be null bytes.

Comment: Thanks so much! So, would making it a 60-byte field work? And would it be the programmatically "correct"/"best" way of doing it?

Comment: @MinimumEntropy I don't have enough context here to tell you what the right way to do anything would be.  I don't know any hash function that has a 60-byte output, and you're talking about characters here, so whatever it is you're doing sounds sketchy already.

Comment: PHP's password_hash function returns the used algorithm, cost and salt all in one 60 char string

Comment: @MinimumEntropy That function returns a string, so you should be using a string/character field.  If you were storing binary data (such as the raw output of a hash function) then storing it as binary is most efficient.

Comment: Thank you. So a simple varchar(60) would have been better?

Comment: I'd use `char`, since you know the length.

Comment: @MinimumEntropy - To store the result of `password_hash()` it is recommended to use `varchar(255)`. This makes it future proof, so the hash algorithm can be changed when it should be necessary.